# Android: startActivity(intent) whithout open browser

Tags: android, android-intent

I use this code for download link from url and save to sd card ( whith smartphone )

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://yourname.com/file.mp3"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But after start this intent , browser open and after download link

How download from url without open browser ?

Comment: Best answer for Your Questions

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download in background then use `DownloadManager`, because using intent will always launch browser in foreground. A simple tutorial for using DownloadManager is

```
http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/
```

Or you can also look here

```
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/11/download-manager-in-android-with-example.html#.VZDtUfmqqko
```

Comment: Thx, How import DownloadManager into library ?

Comment: You don't need to import downloadManager to library, just use it in your source code

Comment: I use this code but error : DownloadManager cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Check your minimum API Level in Manifest, It should be more that 8

Comment: It is 8 : <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> , i change to 16 but not worked

Comment: If it is more than 8, it should work, can you post the source code here and error also

Comment: After change to 16 error is : Attribute minSdkVersion (16) is higher than the project target API level (8)

Comment: then either use minimum sdkVesion =9 or increase your targetSdkVersion >=16

Comment: also increase your targetSdkVersion, i.e. your targetSdkVersion should be always greater than or equal to minimum sdk version

Comment: Thx, after click for download error : 06-29 08:13:22.180: I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(384): tagSocketFd(50, -255, 10041) failed with errno-2

Answer (score 0):

Try this code place this function in your Activity and pass required parameter and this function start download process automatically and after save this function retutn you downloaded file as a FILE.

```
public File downloadFile(Context context, String url, String filename) {
            File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Your_Foldername");

            if (!direct.exists()) {
                direct.mkdirs();
            } else {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "Your_Foldername" + "/" + filename);
                if(file.exists())
                file.delete();
            }

            DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

            Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);

            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                    DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                    .setAllowedOverRoaming(false).setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setDescription("Downloading Share Image for " + context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/" + "Your_Foldername", filename);

            mgr.enqueue(request);
            return direct;
        }
```